# The maximum value of specific columns of a row java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have the following two-dimensional arrays :

```
1 | 5 | 6 | 16| 8 | 9 | 
9 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 
1 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 8 |

int[][] arr = {{1 ,5 ,6 ,16,8 ,9 }, {9 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,7 ,6 }, {1 ,2 ,4 ,7 ,3 ,8 }};
```

I need to find the maximum value for a specific row and columns, for example for the 1st row, second and 5th column maximum is 8.

Comment: Yes, you can have the maximum value of certain columns in a certain row.  Did you try to code anything for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to use Stream API for such purposes:

```java
public static int findMax(int from, int to, int row, int[][] arr) {
    // validate input parameters
    assert 0 <= row && row < arr.length;
    assert 0 <= from && from <= to && to < arr[row].length;

    return Arrays.stream(arr[row])     // IntStream of numbers in the given row
                 .skip(from)           // start `from` column
                 .limit(to - from + 1) // check until `to` column
                 .max()                // pick max value
                 .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE); // if max not found (empty array)
}
```

Test:

```java
int[][] arr = {
    {1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    {9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6},
    {1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8}
};

System.out.println(findMax(1, 2, 0, arr));
```

Output:

```
6
```

---

The same may be implemented using common loops:

```java
public static int findMax(int from, int to, int row, int[][] arr) {
    assert 0 <= row && row < arr.length;
    assert 0 <= from && from <= to && to < arr[row].length;

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, arr[row][i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

*Note*: in both examples 0-based array indexes are used for row and columns: 1 refers to the 2nd column, 2 refers to the 3rd column, 0 refers to the 1st row.

---

**Update**
As it may be needed to look for maximum in *a set* of columns (not between the two columns inclusively), it may be implemented as:

```java
public static int findMaxInColumns(int[][] arr, int row, int ... cols) {
    assert 0 <= row && row < arr.length;

    return Arrays.stream(cols)
            // optional filter to prevent ArrayOutOfBoundsException
            .filter(col -> col >= 0 && col < arr[row].length)
            .map(col -> arr[row][col])
            .max()
            .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE );
}
```

Test for the same `arr`:

```java
System.out.println("max in cols 1, 3, 4: " + findMaxInColumns(arr, 0, 1, 3, 4));
```

Output:

```
max in cols 1, 3, 4: 8
```

Comment: thank you , I tried all of this, but the problem is if the columns are not adjacent how we will loop from to , for example if we want to compare the values ​​of column 2, column 4 and column 7 for example and obtain at the end the maximum value

Comment: You wrote this requirement in your question _maximum value between the second column and the third column_ (BETWEEN from AND to), and in the comment you offered _totally_ different case (IN (from, to)).  If we have no information but only two column indexes, how should we distinguish a _range_ and specific columns?

Comment: you are right, maybe I didn't explain my problem well, I just gave an example of second and third column

Comment: try my second solution, you can set any lists of rows and cols

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience but if I wanted to have the index of the column of the maximum value for example in this case 4

Answer (score 1):

If you start indexing from 1 then you can do like this:

```
    int[][] arr = {{1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8}};

    int rowNum = 1;
    int firstColNum = 2;
    int lastColNum = 3;

    int maxVal = Arrays.stream(arr[rowNum-1])
                                      .limit(lastColNum)
                                      .skip(firstColNum)
                                      .max().getAsInt();

    System.out.println(maxVal);
```

You may put your rows and col numbers in arrays or lists:

```
    int[][] arr = {{1, 5, 6, 16, 8, 9}, {9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8}};

    Integer maxVal = null;

    int[] rowNums = {1};
    int[] colNums = {5,1};

    List<Integer> resList = new ArrayList();

    for (int rowIndx : rowNums) {
        for (int colIndx : colNums) {
            int currVal = arr[rowIndx - 1][colIndx - 1];

            if (maxVal==null) maxVal=currVal;
            else if (maxVal < currVal) maxVal = currVal;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(maxVal);
```

Or you can do in a such way more complex using stream API:

```
    int[][] arr = {{1 ,5 ,6 ,16,8 ,9 }, {9 ,1 ,3 ,4 ,7 ,6 }, {1 ,2 ,4 ,7 ,3 ,8 }};

    //set list of rows 
    List<Integer> rowNums = Arrays.asList(1);
    //set list of columns 
    List<Integer> colNums = Arrays.asList(1,5);

    int maxVal = rowNums.stream().map(i -> arr[i-1])
                         .flatMapToInt(innerArr -> colNums.stream()
                                                          .mapToInt(i -> innerArr[i-1]))
                         .max().getAsInt();

    System.out.println(maxVal);
```

Comment: A couple of minor comments: 1) either assignment `maxVal = 0;` needs to be `maxVal = null;` or condition `if(maxVal == null)` may be removed; 2) collecting to intermediate list `listArr` is not needed, it is possible to join stream operations: `rowNums.stream().map(i -> arr[i - 1]).flatMapToInt(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your comment. With your hepl the code got better